# Where can i find a Dataset for history of Australian federal politicians

Tags: data-request, australia

To answer this question https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/what-is-the-most-common-surname-in-the-history-of-australian-federal-politics I want to find the dataset that contains all the australian federal politicians and their names.  I could not find a dataset on the australian parliament website.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've tried wikidata.org and similar sources?

Comment: getting closer, there was some there but it did not go back far just a few years.